# CampaignMember SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, campaign-member

In my apex code I want to retrieve a campaignMember with a given email.

The query

```
[SELECT status FROM campaignMember WHERE email = :emailVar];
```

Returns the problem message

> No such column email on entity 'CampaignMember'.

However there is an email field on the CampaignMember. When I write the same query in the 'Query Editor' it returns the correct record.

Why is this happening, and what is the best solution?

Comment: did you check FLS on Email field for running user?

Comment: It's set to 'read-only'

Comment: A workaround is to create a formula field to reference email on CampaignMember object. Please see thislink for more details : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EYIhQAO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a version issue for your Apex class. Update it to V43

Per the [V43 docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm?search_text=campaignmember), Email is a supported field on CampaignMember

In my Dev Console, executing `select Email from CampaignMember` works fine in both queryeditor and anonymous apex

Comment: That's good to know, I'll flag that Idea so they'll mark it as delivered

Answer (score 2):

That is a special field that is not available to Apex or the API before version 43.  (This Idea is now obsolete because it was delivered in Summer 18 ver 43:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kqeAAAQ)

Comment: note that if there are large numbers of campaignmembers, a query on a formula field could be a very long table scan